# Copiar dados de uma base de dados para outra postgress

Tags: postgresql

Como faço para copiar dados de uma tabela de uma base de dados para outra tabela de uma outra base de dados em postgress

É possível fazer algo como?

```
INSERT INTO V(ID,D,S)
VALUES(SELECT ID,D,S
FROM D.A)
```

Comment: O que você já tentou?

Comment: Dependendo do número de tabelas, backup e restores parece mais simples. É possível via consulta também

Comment: Acho que a galera negativou ele por causa do MAIUSCULO QUE ESTAVA ANTES.

Answer (score 4):

É possível fazer isso com o postgres através de uma extensão chamada `dblink` a instalação está na pasta contrib ou shared\extention do postgres, é um script basta executar ele e serão criadas 40 e poucas funções na database selecionada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A sintaxe é meio verbosa mas na prática é composta por 3 partes, a primeira é a definição do insert na database local, a segunda é a definição da conexão remota e o select, a última é a tipagem do retorno.

```
INSERT INTO tabela_local(id, nome, descricao, data)
    SELECT id, nome, descricao, data FROM 
    dblink('host=hostRemoto user=postgres password=senha dbname=base_remota'::text,
    'SELECT id, nome, descricao, data FROM tabela_remota'::text, false)
    tabela_temp(id integer, nome character varying, descricao character varying, data date)
)
```

Comment: ESTA A DAR-ME ESTE ERRO    ERROR:  relation "alfabeto" does not exist
CONTEXT:  Error occurred on dblink connection named "unnamed": could not execute query.

Comment: @user2964140, coloca sua consulta aqui no comentário.

Comment: @user2964140, campos/tabelas com o nome maiusculo vc deve usar entre aspas duplas.

Comment: sim era isso ;)

Comment: @user2964140, se resolveu o problema marque a resposta como aceita e aproveite e veja [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/91)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode simplicar usando esse codigo, alterando os valores das tabelas

```
$ pg_dump -U postgres -aD -t tb_tabela1-t tb_tabela2 database
```

Comment: ja usei mas nao reconhece

Comment: Poderia explicar o que essa linha faz?

Comment: A saída destes comandos nada mais são do que arquivos textos que contém um padrão de exibição de cada linha.

Answer (score 1):

Eu acho q vc vai precisar da extensao dblink - 
dblink -- executes a query in a remote database

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/contrib-dblink-function.html

http://www.underdog-projects.net/2009/02/copy-a-table-across-databases-via-dblink/

```
insert into realtime (symbol,date,price)
select * from dblink('dbname=stocks',
              'select name,date,(bid+ask)/2 as price
              from realtime
              where date > to_date(''20081231'',''yyyyMMDD'') and date < to_date(''20090201'',''yyyyMMDD'')')
         as t1 (name character varying,date timestamp,price numeric);
```

Comment: É melhor postar parte do código aqui, e não em links externos. Os  links podem deixar de existir e a resposta ficará vaga

Comment: Essa resposta está certa +1. Não sei porque levou -1.

Comment: pq o moderador nao esperou nem um minuto para uma ediçao em q coloquei o codigo exemplo

Answer (score 0):

Tudo depende da periodicidade disso.

Se for somente uma vez, você pode fazer um backup da tabela pelo `pg_admin` e um `restore` no outro banco.

Se você quiser enviar somente alguns registros, você pode usar o comando `COPY`.
Segue exemplo abaixo:

```
COPY (select * from tabela) '/tmp/bkp_tabela'
```

Se o banco que você for fazer o `restore` estiver no mesmo servidor, basta somente rodar o comando

```
COPY nomeTabelaDestino TO '/tmp/bkp_tabela'
```

Se o banco destino estiver em outro servidor, basta levar o arquivo `bkp_tabela` que está no `diretorio /tmp`.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar dblink
1. Primeiramente cria uma extensão com auxilio de uma query no Postgres:

> create extension dblink
>   2. Logo em seguida
>   select [nome_da_coluna] from dblink('dbname=[nome_do_banco_antigo] options=-csearch_path=_', 'select [nome_da_coluna] from  [nome_do_banco_novo] ') as t ( [nome_da_coluna][tipo de dado que vai ser repassado])

ex: select name from dblink('dbname=banco_-velho options=-csearch_path=_',
            'select name from public.social_pessoa') as t (nome text)