# Copiar um registro de uma banco de dados com várias tabelas relacionadas

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estou tentando copiar um registro de uma tabela do banco banco de dados, mas o problema é que essa tabela tem muitas ligações, chaves estrangeiras. O registro deve envolver umas 40 tabelas. Existe alguma forma de eu fazer isso? Só preciso duplicar o registro alterando um único valor. É possível?

Não consegui fazer nada.

Comment: Não tem como fazer um insert trocando apenas o que precisa? Pode nos explicar melhor?

Comment: Explicando melhor é assim, tenho uns registros aqui no banco, que correspondem a um questionário, só que um questionário tem pessoas envolvidas, tem horas trabalhadas, vários dados, que estão em outra tabela... Eu queria duplicar um questionário, só que pra isso, tem replicar os dados em todas as tabelas.

Comment: Sim é possível => [Copiar dados de uma base de dados para outra postgress](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/98692/91)

Comment: Não é bem isso rray, é copiar pras mesmas tabelas. Quando eu abrir o programa que consome esse banco, eu quero que tenha 2 questionários, um igual ao outro, apenas com o ID diferente.

Comment: As tabelas estão na mesma database? qual é o problema que vc tem agora? montar a consulta? violação de FK?

Comment: O problema é tipo assim: Vamos supor que eu duplique uma linha da tabela QUESTIONÁRIOS, ai vamos supor que cada questionário tenha um ID, 1 e 2, nas outras tabelas eu tenho registros referenciando ID 1, eu preciso que esses registros também sejam duplicados, mas referenciando o ID 2. Deu pra entender mais ou menos? Preciso duplicar o questionário por completo.