# Consulta entre duas databases diferentes postgresql cakephp

Tags: postgresql, cakephp

Tenho dois banco de dados distintos **clientes** e **tickets**.

Onde na tabela **cliente_tickets** do banco de dados **clientes** é armazenado uma configuração da qual eu preciso para acessar determinados valores no banco **tickets**. Sendo assim, tentei utilizar o `construct` do `cakephp` para conectar em um banco e em outro, exemplo:

- *inicialmente está conectado ao banco de dados **clientes**;*

´ **$this->ClienteTicket ...** é do banco de dados **clientes**, mas ao conectar ao banco de dados **tickets**, perco o acesso à essa tabela, daí não sei como prosseguir com o método `find` do `cakephp`, para exibir os dados que eu quero, alguém sabe como prosseguir ?

```
$this->loadModel('ClienteTicket');

$cliente_tickets = $this->ClienteTicket->find('all');

//Altera o banco de dados para o Tickets
$this->Cliente->construct('tickets');

$this->loadModel('Project');
$this->loadModel('Tracker');
$this->loadModel('Issue');
$this->loadModel('CustomField');
$this->loadModel('CustomFieldsProject');
$this->loadModel('CustomValue');

$tickets = $this->ClienteTicket->find('all', array(
        'fields' => array('Issue.id', 'Tracker.name', 'Issue.subject',
            'Issue.created_on', 'IssueStatuse.name', 'CustomValue.value'),
        'joins' => array(
            array('table' => 'custom_fields',
                'alias' => 'CustomField',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => [
                    'ClienteTicket.cf_id = CustomField.id',
                ],
            ),
            array('table' => 'custom_values',
                'alias' => 'CustomValue',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => [
                    'CustomValue.custom_field_id = CustomField.id',
                ],
            ),
            array('table' => 'custom_fields_trackers',
                'alias' => 'CustomFieldsTracker',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => [
                    'CustomFieldsTracker.custom_field_id = CustomField.id',
                ],
            ),
            array('table' => 'trackers',
                'alias' => 'Tracker',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => [
                    'CustomFieldsTracker.tracker_id = Tracker.id',
                ],
            ),
            array('table' => 'custom_fields_projects',
                'alias' => 'CustomFieldsProject',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => [
                    'CustomFieldsProject.custom_field_id = CustomField.id',
                ],
            ),
            array('table' => 'projects',
                'alias' => 'Project',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => [
                    'CustomFieldsProject.project_id = Project.id',
                ],
            ),
            array('table' => 'issues',
                'alias' => 'Issue',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => [
                    'CustomValue.customized_id = Issue.id',
                ]),
            array('table' => 'issue_statuses',
                'alias' => 'IssueStatuse',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => [
                    'Issue.status_id = IssueStatuse.id',
                ],
            ),
        ),
        'conditions' => [
            'CustomValue.value like \'' . $cod_cliente . '\''
        ],
        'group' => 'Issue.id, Tracker.name, Issue.subject,
        Issue.created_on, IssueStatuse.name, CustomValue.value',
        'limit' => 5,
        'order' => ['Issue.id' => 'DESC']
    ));
```

Comment: No banco que tem a tabela de `clientes` eu criaria uma view com o resultado da tabela de `tickets` usando o dblink. [Copiar dados de uma base de dados para outra postgres](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/98685/91)

Comment: O problema de fazer isso é que demoraria muito para mostrar os resultados, sendo que existem tabelas com pelo menos 3 milhões de registros :Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro, armazenei em uma variável as informações das tabelas do banco **cliente** que eram pertinentes para eu usar no banco **tickets**.

Após realizei a conexão ao banco **tickets**.
`$this->Cliente->construct('tickets');`

Logo armazenei em uma variável `$SQL_Tickets` a consulta SQL que retornava os valores que era preciso, então onde precisava dos valores das tabelas do banco **clientes**, eu utilizei a variável criada.

Após utilizei:

```
$tickets = $this->Cliente->query($SQL_Tickets);

//Voltei para o banco anterior
$this->Cliente->construct('default');
```