# Copiar dados de um BD para outro, sempre que tiver um novo registro

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Preciso copiar os dados de um BD-1 PGSQL para utro BD-2 PGSQL sempre que tiver um novo registro. Estava tentando dar um SELECT dentro do INSERT mas está dando falha com a conexão, já verifiquei varíos posts mas não encontrei uma solução, alguém poderia dar alguma ideia de como fazer ou seria assim mesmo como estava fazendo ?

OBS: Não posso modificar nada do BD-1.

```
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO call_lost.teste (cod, data, hora, telefone)
SELECT q_num, time_start, from_userpart, ts_servicing FROM database_single.callcent_queuecalls WHERE ts_servicing = '00:00:00'";
$resultset = pg_query($conn1, $sql1) or die("database error:" . pg_errormessage($conn1));
```

Comment: Qual erro de conexão?

Comment: @DiegoSchmidt ele não está fazendo a conexão com os dois bancos, só faz a conexão individualmente.

Comment: Pode usar o [dblink](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/98692/91) só não vai sincronizar sozinho precisa chamar ele no seu código ou via cron.

Comment: @rray acabei de ver esse post estava pesquisando um pouco mais sobre, sabe me informar se preciso ter eles nos dois BD's ?

Comment: Precisa 'instalar' ele somente no DB que vai gravar as informações do outro.

Comment: @rray Ótimo,ai eu jogando o código no cron ele seria executado por um determinado tempo, correto ? Ou teria como colocar uma condição para que fizesse o `INSERT` apenas quando tiver um registro novo no BD-1.

Comment: Pronto não. Teria que montar uma lógica prorpria, no DB-1 se possível poderia colocar uma coluna datetime com a data inclusão do registro, aí na hora de chamar o cron faz já filtra pela última vez que ele rodou.

Comment: @rray não consigo criar essa coluna, DB-1 é de um outro sistema de terceiros, só tenho permissão para realizar consultas.